# Appending text to label tkinter

Tags: python, string, tkinter, label, append

I'm stuck with a script in Python 3. I want to append additional text to already existing label in tkinter.

I attempted this:

```
def labelConfig(string,append=False):
    if append:
        label.configure(text+=string)
    else:
        label.configure(text=string)
```

But it won't compile... How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a tkinter problem, this applies to all of python. You cannot use `+=` when setting a positional argument in a function call. Instead, you must get the value, modify it however you want, then assign the new value to the widget.

For example:

```
def labelConfig(string,append=False):
    if append:
        text = label.cget("text") + string
        label.configure(text=text)
    else:
        label.configure(text=string)
```

Answer (score 4):

Apart from Bryan Oakley's answer, it also possible to use `+=` if you access the text of the label as a value from a dictionary:

```
def labelConfig(string,append=False):
    if append:
        label['text'] += string
    else:
        label['text'] = string
```

All options that can be getted or setted with `configure` have the equivalent syntax `widget['option'] = value`, which can be used in situations like this one.

Answer (score 0):

the `text+=string` is a statement so it will not return anything. You will need to first get value from label, then concatenate those strings and then pass them as argument